# run time error 424 object required on attempting to make a label transparent

Tags: winforms, vb6, runtime-error

I am using VB 6.0 and I am trying to make the backcolor of a label transparent.
It may look like a silly question but I have goggled the issue and tried so many ways but non of them have worked.

I have the following code

```
   Private Sub Form_Load()
   Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
   End Sub
```

but when I run the project it gives me the error "run time error 424 object required"

As nobody have figured out the answer yet this extra info might help you find out the problem

when I replace the previus cod with

```
    Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

I get an error on the "Color" saying "Compile error: invalid qualifier"
I think the program doesn't recognise the "Color" for some reason!! Plz help

Comment: This is some kind of unholy mix of VB6 and VB.NET code.  A VB6 Label control has a BackStyle property.

Comment: It has both BackColor and BackStyle properties, the property was not causing the error but as @Beaner said there is no Color library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **Color** library. That is the source of your error. Try setting the BackStyle to transparent.

```
Label1.BackStyle = vbTransparent '0
```

Comment: you are right thank you I also found another way to do that

         Label1.BackStyle = 0

thanks again